# English / French speech to IPA

Tags: phonetics, speech-recognition

Are there any open-sourced library / Deep Learning models that convert an audio clip of a word to its IPA representation? In this case, the audio is from a **non-native speaker** and the goal is to generate the **corresponding IPA representation of the word as uttered** by the speaker. This representation is expected to be much different than the 'correct' or 'true' IPA representation. Basically I want to understand the deep learning model behind https://elsaspeak.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

There is no program that converts samples speech to IPA. Some program might appear to do that, by converting an utterance of language Z into its orthographic form then following conventional text-to-IPA rules to yield a psuedo-trancription, which that would not detect variations (among native speakers) between [i] and [ɛ] as the first vowel of "economic". There is an insufficient corpus of expert IPA productions to make such a program possible (example: there are no expert samples of coda consonant; there are no expert samples of [t] between high vowels or round vowels). For what you are describing, you need actual expert reference values, not well-meaninged attempts at producing reference values (such as the Smalley tapes).